# How to read a specific field in ADO.NET Entity Data Model Object on Postback event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have a dropdownlist that is populated from a database as:

 **Controller**

```
PayrollDb pdb = new PayrollDb ();
var addBranchGui = new branch();
addBranchGui.BranchTypes = new SelectList(pdb.branchtypes,"Id", "Type");
```

**View**

```
<p>Branch Type:@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BranchType, Model.BranchTypes, "Choose an option")</p>
```

This codes correctly populates the dropdownload list. Problem arises when user selects an option in the dropdownlist and submits the form and I catch the input data on `[HttpPost` action method and insert it into a database table, it is the `"Id"` field that gets inserted when I want the `"Type"` field to be inserted.

I can understand that on Postback event, browsers is reading `"Id"` field. Can someone please guide me how I can command the browser to give me the `"Type"` field so I can insert that into database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `SelectList` constructor, you are specifying `Id` as the data value field for the dropdown.

```
addBranchGui.BranchTypes = new SelectList(pdb.branchtypes,"Id", "Type");
```

So it will render the dropdown like this

```
<SELECT name="BranchType">
   <option value="2">HeadOffice</head>
   <option value="4">Branch</head>
</SELECT>
```

So change it to use `Type` as the datavalue field.

```
addBranchGui.BranchTypes = new SelectList(pdb.branchtypes,"Type", "Type");
```

This will render a SELECT element with same value for the option value and the option text

```
<SELECT name="BranchType">
   <option value="HeadOffice">HeadOffice</head>
   <option value="Branch">Branch</head>
</SELECT>
```

Now when user posts the form, you will get the text value(the type) in `BranchType` field